# Rails 4 - Validate that a User doesn't have more than a certain amount of relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
    validates :games, length: { maximum: 3 }

end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    validates :user, presence: true
    validates_associated :user

end
```

I want to make sure that no user has more than 3 games, but the validation does not seem to work.

**Why?**

Comment: Are you set on using a validation? How about a before_action?

Comment: Well, I could do that. But it is a constriction I want to set between then models. So wouldn't it make more sense to do it in the model?

Comment: Are you adding it as a precaution? Do you have views? You can hide the create button after the use already has 3 games? Unless you're dealing with a API call?

Comment: Yes, I can do many things. But Id like to set it as a validation rule

Comment: This link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591257/validating-length-of-habtm-association-without-saving

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom validation method. As is shown in the Rails guide:
[custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
  validate :has_three_games_or_less

  private:

  def has_three_games_or_less
    if games.count > 3.
      errors.add_to_base("can't have more than 3 games")
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_length_of#865-Can-be-used-with-has-many-associations), it should be achievable using the code you have.

If it doesn't work, you could use `inverse_of` to store the associated objects in memory (hence making them available to your validator):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :games, inverse_of: :user
   validates :games, length: { maximum: 3 }
end

#app/models/game.rb
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :games
end
```

You could alternatively set up a custom method to do it for you:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :games, inverse_of: :user
   validate :max_games

   private

   def max_games
      errors.add(:base, "You cannot have more than 3 games on this account.") unless games.size <= 3
   end
end
```